# Match on a text field with a token graph filter and keyword tokenizer - why order of query terms matters?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `text` field filled by the `word_delimiter` filter, using the `keyword` tokenizer, to produce additional tokens and would like to search for them (`match` operation) regardless of their position in the query string, e.g.

1. works - document gets found:

```
GET test-position/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title.keywords": {
        "query": "yuio zxcv",
        "operator": "or"
      }}}}
```

2. does not work  - document does not get found, I don't really get why? The analyzer produces **the same tokens** for the query string.

```
GET test-position/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title.keywords": {
        "query": "zxcv yuio",
        "operator": "or"
      }}}}
```

- Index settings

```
PUT test-position
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": "1",
    "number_of_replicas": "0",
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "word_delimiter_filter": {
          "type": "word_delimiter_graph",
          "catenate_words": "true",
          "catenate_numbers": "true",
          "catenate_all": "true",
          "preserve_original": "true",
          "generate_number_parts": "true"
        }},
      "analyzer": {
        "wordpart_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "word_delimiter_filter"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }}}},
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "standard", 
        "fields": {
          "keywords": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "wordpart_analyzer"
          }}}}}}
```

- Test document

```
PUT test-position/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"title":"asdf qwer yuio zxcv"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it really helps to thoroughly formulate your question :)

I got the answer now: the "magic" parameter is [index_options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-options.html). Adding

```
"index_options": "freqs"
```

to the field mapping solved the problem, as the default behaviour is to store term positions (or order) along with docs number and terms frequencies when indexing.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting your solution. I didn't think that a `match` query wouldn't include results because the term positions were out of order. Doesn't seem to happen with a different tokenizer (`whitespace` or `standard`).